# Feature selection based on correlation test between quantitative discrete and dichotomous variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, feature-selection

I want to perform a binary classification on CLAIM_FLAG where one of my explanatory variable is YOJ (Year of Joining) and the range is from 0 to 23.

I plotted out the relation between these two and it seems to me YOJ has no effect on CLAIM_FLAG:

[image]

Also the result for Pearson's product-moment correlation is -0.06 but I'm not sure if it is the right test to choose.

My questions are:

1. What is the type of YOJ variable? Can I also treat it as continuous variable? (since one of the assumption of Point-Biserial test is that one variable need to be continuous)
2. Ultimately I want to know whether if I should include YOJ in my model or not and what are my options to test it against the target.

Any help is appreciated.